# Sakila db SQL find customers who have rented the same movie more than 3 times

Tags: sql

I am totally stuck on my homework. I am working with the Sakila sample db. I am supposed to write a query that will give me a list of all the customers who have rented >3 same movie. This is what I have so far:

```
 select concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) as Customer_name
    from customer c
    inner join rental r on r.customer_id = c.customer_id
    inner join inventory i on i.inventory_id = r.inventory_id
    inner join film f on f.film_id = i.film_id
    inner join film_category fc on fc.film_id = f.film_id
    inner join category ca on ca.category_id = fc.category_id
    where name = '' and rental_id > 3
    group by Customer_name
    having count(*) > 3
    order by Customer_name;
```

Comment: Firstly, what RDBMS are you using? Tag it in the question. Secondly, give a minimal, reproductive example of the tables you have, here is a link that explains how to do so: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Third, what do you get as an output from your query? Lastly, homework usually means that you also had a lesson similar to the homework. And even though Stack overflow is for helping learn, it's not really the place to expect people to do your homework, instead ask your teacher if there are any problems, that's their job anyway.

Comment: I m not asking for the solution it self, i m asking to explain where i may went wrong or missed some info actually explain me how can i reach my goal with the answer it self. about the tables you´r right I will add them. And even though Stack overflow is for helping learn thanks for your Policy terms advise

Comment: Right now you're getting customers who have rented any movie > 3 times. If you want to count specific movies, add movie to the GROUP BY.